# R neuralnet parameter tuning

Tags: r, r-caret

I've been trying to play around with neural networks in R, using Caret package. I do not understand, why my code in this case does not work. As far as I know, tune parameters should be saved in a grid, is that not the case?

```
library(caret)

# load the iris dataset
data(iris)
# define training control
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
# train the model
grid <- expand.grid(layer1 = c(1,5,6))
model <- train(Species~., data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="neuralnet", tuneGrid = grid)
# summarize results
print(model)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `method = "neuralnet"` is only for regression. You are trying to do a classification.

Comment: @phiver I think `neuralnet` can do classification with parameter `linear.output = FALSE` because the documentation says `If act.fct should not be applied to the output neurons set linear output to TRUE, otherwise to FALSE.`. In other words, `linear.output = FALSE`   sets logistic regression from the default setting `act.fct = "logistic"`. So then you can do binary classification

Comment: @AgileBean, that might be the case when using the neuralnet package, but not when you are using caret. The method currently implemented in caret is only for using regression.